# What does おとなしく見える mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

借りてきた猫のようにおとなしく見えても、実は猫をかぶっているだけかも。

Without the おとなしく I understand the first half of sentence as meaning, "Looks like a cat that was borrowed". But I'm not sure what additional information the おとなしく is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おとなしく見える means "looks docile", and nothing more. Actually this is the easiest part of the sentence, and I'm wondering why you're asking about it specifically. Do you understand [借りてきた猫](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%80%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E7%8C%AB) and [猫を被る](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%8C%AB%E3%82%92%E8%A2%AB%E3%82%8B) are both idioms with fixed meanings? Or maybe have you temporarily forgotten [見える takes a ku-form](https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)?

> 借りてきた猫のようにおとなしく見えても、実は猫をかぶっているだけかも。
> Even if they look docile like a borrowed cat, they may actually be pretending to be harmless.

Comment: I had no idea those were idioms! I think that's what was making it hard for me to understand. "Docile like a borrowed cat" didn't make sense to me so I thought I must not be understanding the sentence correctly.

Comment: For my part, I was unfamiliar with 大人しい, and would not have guessed it to have that meaning from the root 大人.